# Removing all but most recent file whose name contains a substring

Tags: bash, replace

I am looking for a bash script (or one-liner) to accomplish the following:

1. Check to see if there is more than one file containing the substring "slurm-"
2. If so, remove all of the files containing the substring except for the newest one

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) is quite relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above isn't exceptionally efficient with a very long list of files, but (1) it's fast with a short list (low constant-time startup cost), and (2) it's very explicit about how it operates (easy to read and understand).

```
shopt -s nullglob
candidates=( slurm-* )

(( ${#candidates[@]} < 2 )) && exit 0    ## nothing to do if <2 files exist

latest=${candidates[0]}                  ## populate latest variable w/ first
for candidate in "${candidates[@]}"; do  ## loop through the whole set
  if [[ $candidate -nt $latest ]]; then  ## and if one is newer, call it "latest"
    latest=$candidate
  fi
done

for candidate in "${candidates[@]}"; do  ## iterate through the whole set
  if [[ $candidate != "$latest" ]]; then ## and for everything but the latest file
    rm -f -- "$candidate"                ## run a deletion
  fi
done
```

Comment: This is great, thank you! I think you made a typo, however. Shouldn't it be `if [[ $latest -ot` instead of `-nt`?

Comment: Heh. thinko rather than a typo -- the intent was `[[ $candidate -nt $latest ]]`. Edited appropriately, thank you for the catch. :)

Answer (score 0):

Answering the XY problem, you might find it a better course of action to actually add `#SBATCH -o output.txt` to your submission file to overwrite the Slurm output file every time, if your intent is to keep a clean working directory while submitting several times in a row the same job until it properly runs.